# Three.js with Node.js on a server - how to load a TEXTURE?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, three.js, textures

I have a trouble with **Three.js** for loading a **texture** and applying to a mesh cube.
In local, I know there are some issues like running the html file on a apache server with wamp (localhost).

But when I use **Node.js** and socket.io, how to fix it ?
First, to load three.js, I have to put the web adress of the script src instead of a local "three.js" :

> http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js

It works but how about the texture ?

**Neither a local or an internet adress for the texture is working...**

```
 //var mapUrl = "mercury.jpg"; 
    var mapUrl = "http://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/skybox/px.jpg"; 
    var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(mapUrl); // its not working with both
```

And if I put my code on a **web server running with Node.js like Cloud9**, how to fix it ? (same problem as in local with Node.js).

Thank you for your attention.

---

Here is my complete code.

*Server*

```
var http    =   require('http');
var fs      =   require('fs');

// Creation du serveur
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // On lit notre fichier app.html
    fs.readFile('gl.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
        res.end(content);
    });

  });

var io = require("socket.io");
io = io.listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('send', function () {
    socket.broadcast.emit('rec');

  }); // send

});  // connection


app.listen(8080);
```

---

*Client (gl.html)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to WebGL</title>
</head>
<body onLoad="onLoad();" style="">
<h1>Webgl</h1>
<div id="container" style="width:95%; height:80%; position:absolute;"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="Three.js"></script> not working-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
    var socket = io.connect();

    var renderer = null, 
        scene = null, 
        camera = null,
        cube = null,
        animating = false;

    function onLoad()
    {
        // Grab our container div
        var container = document.getElementById("container");

        // Create the Three.js renderer, add it to our div
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        // Create a new Three.js scene
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // Put in a camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, container.offsetWidth / container.offsetHeight, 1, 4000 );
        camera.position.set( 0, 0, 3 );

        // Create a directional light to show off the object
        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.5);
        light.position.set(0, 0, 1);
        scene.add( light );






        // Create a shaded, texture-mapped cube and add it to the scene
        // First, create the texture map

   //   var mapUrl = "mercury.jpg";
  var mapUrl = "http://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/skybox/px.jpg";
        var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(mapUrl); // not working with both !!!






        // Now, create a Phong material to show shading; pass in the map
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: map });

        // Create the cube geometry
        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);

        // And put the geometry and material together into a mesh
        cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        // Turn it toward the scene, or we won't see the cube shape!

       // cube.rotation.x = Math.PI / 5;
        cube.rotation.x = 0.5;
        //cube.rotation.y = Math.PI / 5;

        // Add the cube to our scene
        scene.add( cube );

        // Add a mouse up handler to toggle the animation
        addMouseHandler();

        // Run our render loop
        run();


    }

    function run()
    {
        // Render the scene
        renderer.render( scene, camera );

        // Spin the cube for next frame
        if (animating)
        {
            cube.rotation.y -= 0.01;
            //cube.rotation.x += 0.05;
        }

        // Ask for another frame
        //requestAnimationFrame(run);
    setTimeout(run, 1000/60);

    }

    function addMouseHandler()
    {
        var dom = renderer.domElement;

        dom.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
    }

    function onMouseUp  (event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        animating = !animating;

        socket.emit('send'); 

    }

    socket.on('rec', function () {

      animating = !animating;

  });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact i just had to use **express**, place all the files in the folder **public** and name client **index.html**.

Now it works ! How can **close** my question ?

Here is the simple code of the *server* :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into trouble with CORS. CORS state that textures need to be comming from the same base url or needs special handling on server side. This is easily fixable with a proxy. If you are already using a server thaen it shouldn't be too hard to configure it to handle proxy requests.